# Why can't I sleep for a calculated integer?

Tags: go

I am trying to calculate a time to sleep but am stuck. I can sleep for 10 seconds:

```
time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
```

However, I try the following:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    n := time.Now()
    remaining := 10 - int(time.Since(n).Seconds())
    log.Println(reflect.TypeOf(10), reflect.TypeOf(remaining))
    //time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    time.Sleep(remaining * time.Second)
}
```

I get:

```
invalid operation: remaining * time.Second (mismatched types int and time.Duration)
```

remaining is an int, just as 10 is an int. What gives?

[My playground](http://play.golang.org/p/qzvoJ_FPHq)

Comment: the accepted answer linked to does not work....http://play.golang.org/p/jANhmUA_Gw

Comment: Both operands need to be the same type. Example: https://play.golang.org/p/E4RLQEDIWo

Comment: put that as an answer and I'll accept.